# Determine the probability of committing a Type II Error.

Tags: statistics

Suppose X is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0;\mu]$, with $\mu$ unknown. The null hypothesis is that $\mu = 2.5$ and the alternative hypothesis is that $\mu \geq 2.5$. 
We test the hypothesis by sampling $X_1$ and $X_2$ from $X$ and taking the maximum of the two as our test statistic $T$. 
We decide to reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_1$ when $T \geq 2$. 
Suppose that the real value of $\mu$ is equal to $3$. 
Determine the Probability of committing a Type II Error.

I have some problem to compute the Probability of committing a Type II Error in this exercise, how should I start it, do I have to convert to N(0,1) distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\beta$ denote the probability of a type II error under the assumption that $\mu = 3$. This means $T < 2$ although values up to $\mu = 3$ can be assumed. Then

- $\beta = P_{\mu = 3}(T <2) = P_{\mu = 3}([0,2]\times[0,2])$
  where
- $P_{\mu = 3}$ is the uniform distribution on the square $[0,3]\times[0,3]$.

Some more info:

Note that you are dealing with squares, as the sample consists of two (independent) random variables. So, you need to consider the squares $2^2$ and $3^2$. Then, you get the correct results.

Maybe you may draw the region $T<2$ on the square with side length $3$ to get a visual grip of what you are calculating.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint, so I have to compute P(T<2|$\mu$=3) right?
My problem is that I don't know how to include the real value of $\mu$ that is equal to 3 and the $\mu=2.5$. I think that the result should be $\frac{2-0}{3-0}=0.66$ but the correct answer is 0.44, where I'm wrong? maybe I should consider also the value 2.5

Comment: You do not need the value $2.5$ here as we are dealing with a type II error: accepting $H_0$ although $H_1: \mu = 3 >2.5$ is true. Since for each $\mu > 2.5$ the probability of the type II error changes, the specific $\mu = 3$ is indicated.

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti : I added some more info for clarification. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now is clear!